# Strictly Increasing function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I am having trouble proving the following questions:

1. Prove that if $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$ then $f$ is measurable (do not assume that $f$ is continuous).
2. Using the above, prove that every nondecreasing function $g$ is
   measurable.

I know that I need to prove that the set $\{x \in [a,b] : f(x) > c\}$ (or some variation of it) is measurable.

Any hints would be most helpful!

Comment: If $f$ is strictly increasing then the preimage of an infinite ray is an infinite ray. Work from there. (An alternate proof that you get stuck with in the nonstrict case is that a monotone function has at most countably many discontinuities.)

Comment: Is there not much to prove, since $f$ is increasing, the set $\{x : f(x) > c\}$ is an interval, and by definition is is measurable?

Comment: Right, I just have to show that $f_n$ is strictly increasing and then use the first statement.

Comment: Are my thoughts in my comment above correct?

Comment: Yes. It occurs to me though that for part 1), the same argument works for the nonstrict case. I don't see why 2) should be a separate problem.

Comment: For the second part, just put $f(x)=g(x)+x$.

Comment: Dear @user0430 I see that, although you have already asked 18 question in this site and received answers in most of them, you have not mark a best answer in any of them. You can do it so by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer that you think is the one that helped you the most. Please [read here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) for more detail.

Answer (score 4):

See W. Rudin: Principles of math. analysis, p. 83, second edition: the set of points of discontinuities of a monotone function on (a,b) is most countable. Thus f is continuous almost every where and hence measurable.